# Pushwoosh SDK Notification Issue

Tags: android

I have integrated the Pushwoosh SDK in my Android Application and it is working fine.

I have done the Cross Platform Setting to run the Android Application on my Blackberry Z10 device, the application is running finely but I am not able to receive the Notification on my Blackberry Z10 device as Android.

I am getting this error:

```
06-06 14:34:21.314: I/QNXNavigatorClient(8708260): Already active: com.packagename.pushdemo
06-06 14:34:21.662: I/QNXNavigatorClient(8708260): PackagesOpenedRunnable: [com.packagename.pushdemo]
06-06 14:34:21.662: I/QNXNavigatorClient(8708260): Shell com.packagename.pushdemo cannot join group, group was already joined
06-06 14:34:21.668: I/ActivityManager(8708260): Displayed com.packagename.pushdemo/.MainActivity: +347ms
06-06 14:34:24.118: E/QNXShrimpClient(8708260): com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER error(10108) = ""
06-06 14:34:24.124: W/ContextImpl(8708260): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendOrderedBroadcast:1061 com.android.server.QNXShrimpClient.onRegisterComplete:162 com.qnx.service.pps.shrimp.ShrimpController.onMessageReceived:128 com.qnx.service.pps.PPSObject.processMessage:292
```

com.qnx.service.pps.PPSObject.access$500:11

I am not able to get the Push Notification on my Blackberry Z10 device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set everything up correctly as in the following guide?
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/blackberry/blackberry-10/blackberryandroid-runtime/

From what I see your app fails to register with BlackBerry. Make sure you have entered the correct **appid** and **ppgurl** in step 4 (android.cfg file).

If you are using BB push trial account the ppgurl should be as in the guide:
http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com